# Prompt command will not work in html

Tags: javascript, html, prompt

I can't figure out how to use javascript prompt command in my html website and I was hoping you guys could help me find my mistake

```html
<head>
        <script type="javascript">
         var pass=prompt("What is the password")
         if(pass="hack"){
      confirm("welcome");
     } 
     else{
      window.close();
     }
    </script>
```

thanks to all my problem was that it didn't like `<script type="javascript">` so I ended up using just `<script>`

Comment: Try moving the SCRIPT tag into the BODY instead of the HEAD.

Comment: Should be `if (pass == "hack")`

Comment: What does "does not work" mean?  It runs just fine in a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `<script>` type was your main problem.  Remove `type="javascript"` and that is fixed.  Also, the if statement should use `==` instead of `=`.  Fix those two things and it'll work just fine.

```html
<script>
  var pass = prompt("What is the password")
  if (pass == "hack") {
    confirm("welcome");
  } else {
    window.close();
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

You want to use `==` and not `=` in your `if` statement

`if (pass == "hack")`

Comment: probably? definitely.

Comment: It still does not work by just fixing this.  Check my answer :)

Comment: @rtome, This does not work.  Check my answer.

Comment: @Igor, This does not work. Check my answer.

Comment: @Tad_Kozusko run it in jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/0y8h0eab/

Comment: thank you but the prompt still does not come up when i load the webpage

Comment: not even in the jsfiddle linked above ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure most browsers won't run UI-interaction code on first load; it's like what they use to prevent popups. Try putting that code inside a function that responds to a button.

```js
function askPass() {
         var pass=prompt("What is the password")
         if(pass==="hack"){
      confirm("welcome");
     } 
     else{
      window.close();
     }
        }
```

```html
  <button onclick="askPass();">Enter</button>
```

Also: Do NOT mix up "=" and "=="! (*"===" usually works the same*). A single-equals *sets* a value. Two equals signs *compare* a value (what you generally want in an "if")